# Python Error when imported from different directory

Tags: python

In mydir/test/testing/pqtest.py

```
import os,sys
lib_path = os.path.abspath('../../lib/mine')
sys.path.append(lib_path)

import Util                <---- get a traceback
import string
import random

# my code
```

---

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "pqtest.py", line 5 in ?
           import Util
       File "mydir/lib/mine/Util.py", line 89
          yield v if l > 0 else ''                       Error is point at if

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, there are other files that import Util.py inside `mydir/lib/mine` that does not have any problems with this file.

So why is it giving me this traceback when i am importing from somewhere else, in this case `mydir/test/testing`?

Syntax error on yield v if l > 0 else ''

```
def expand():
    for l,v in zip(field,val):
        yield l
        yield v if l > 0 else ''
```

this is good for python 2.5 but not for python 2.4

I am assuming I need to tell pqtest.py to use python 2.5 but not sure how

Comment: You've skipped the most iportant part of the Exception traceback: the actual Exception...

Comment: I'm guessing the error is `no such module`?

Comment: @Stephan syntax error

Comment: @ealeon you showed us the wrong code, we are looking for a `yield` statement on line 89 in Util.py

Comment: updated. sorry. @l4mpi

Comment: that code is inside Util.py.... @Stephan there is nothing wrong with Util.py because I am able to run other prog that import Util.py is it a version issue? but they are just few level apart

Comment: @ealeon there is a SYNTAX error in util.py, yes there is probably something wrong in there

Comment: Are you perhaps starting the failing script with python 2.4? The ternary if-then-else operator got introduced in 2.5.

Comment: @Stephan no because if there is indeed syntax error then it would be brought up in other program which imports and run Util.py. must be version issue.

Comment: @l4mpi thats what i was thinking is there something that i can add in for pqtest.py to be a certain python version?

Comment: #!/usr/blah/python2.5 didnt fix. grr

Comment: @ealeon there is definately a syntax error in that file, please show more of it.

Comment: @Stephan its syntax error for python2.4 but not for 2.5. pqtest.py needs to be aware that python 2.5 is being used because 2.4 is default i believe.

Comment: Have you tested that the module can be imported in 2.5? If so, adding the `#!/usr/bin/python2.5` hashbang should do the trick... you know that for the hashbang to work you need to `chmod` the script to be executable and then start it with `./myscript.py`, right?

Comment: thank you!! that fixed the prob. learned something new. thank you @l4mpi

Comment: The other alternative would be to make the code 2.4-compatible. For example, you could replace the one-liner ternary `yield v if l>0 else ''` with `if l>0: yield v` and `else: yield ''`. Then it will have exactly the same behavior in Python 2.5+ as it currently does, but it will also work in 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to change Util.py, the obvious thing to do is to rewrite the code so it's 2.4 compatible. From a comment, the only reason not to change Util.py is:

> … others are depending on it as python 2.5.

But as long as your new code has the exact same effect on Python 2.5+ as the original code, this isn't a problem.

For example, instead of this:

```
def expand():
    for l,v in zip(field,val):
        yield l
        yield v if l > 0 else ''
```

Do this:

```
def expand():
    for l,v in zip(field,val):
        yield l
        if l > 0:
            yield v
        else:
            yield ''
```

Now the other people who are depending on it as python 2.5 will have no change, but it will also work in 2.4.

Comment: this was my original answer, i was told "changing it is not an option"

Comment: @Stephan: [Your original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18111911/1) changed the API of `expand` in a way that would break all users of Utils.py; mine leaves the behavior exactly the same. Also, note that the OP said changing it is "not an option *because others are depending on it as python 2.5*". This change allows those others to continue to depend on it at python 2.5, with no changes to their code required.

Comment: wrong one, my original one before the edit had the same if statement you're showing

Comment: @Stephan: I linked to revision 1, before the edit. At any rate, even if you _did_ have an equivalent answer, the OP clearly didn't understand that, given the quoted wording to his comment. So, instead of changing it to a different answer that wasn't appropriate, you should have explained why you answer wouldn't affect the 2.5 users.

Comment: i made that third answer before he mentioned the 2.5 users the answer was not inappropriate before the change in criteria (btw those links dont work for sub 20k users)

Comment: @Stephan: I don't understand what you're arguing about. From the OP's comments to your question, if you did write this at some point, clearly the OP was confused and thought it would break things for other users, and that's why he rejected it. So explaining to him why it would not break anyone else's code is worth doing. He may still have _another_ reason to reject it that he hasn't given us, of course, but let's at least get past his confusion before assuming that.

Comment: @abarnert yes this would have solved the problem but i went with the approach of forcing pqtest.py to use python2.5 instead. but ill accept this.

Answer (score 1):

run python by itself by typing

```
python
```

If it shows less than 2.5, then you can't use the ternary conditional syntax.  That was introduced in 2.5

If it DOES show 2.5 you can do this

```
python pqtest.py
```

to force `pqtest.py` to use that version

Comment: ah okay but what if python is 2.4?

Comment: you tell me what it is @ealeon

Comment: @ealeon if you see 2.5 when you type python, this solution will work for you.  Let me know if it doesn't

Comment: well python is 2.4 but i solved the problem by making pqtest.py exec and having #!/usr/bin/python2.5 in the code.

Comment: @ealeon i'd recommend posting that as an answer and accepting it since none of these were the right answer for you.